# matplotlib pyplot side-by-side graphics

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, prettyplotlib

I'm trying to put two scatterplots side-by-side in the same figure. I'm also using prettyplotlib to make the graphs look a little nicer. Here is the code

```
fig, ax = ppl.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=1,figsize=(14,6))
for each in ['skimmer','dos','webapp','losstheft','espionage','crimeware','misuse','pos']:
    ypos = df[df['pattern']==each]['ypos_m']
    xpos = df[df['pattern']==each]['xpos_m']
    ax[0] = ppl.scatter(ypos,xpos,label=each)
plt.title("Multi-dimensional Scaling: Manhattan")

for each in ['skimmer','dos','webapp','losstheft','espionage','crimeware','misuse','pos']:
    ypos = df[df['pattern']==each]['ypos_e']
    xpos = df[df['pattern']==each]['xpos_e']
    ax[1] = ppl.scatter(ypos,xpos,label=each)
plt.title("Multi-dimensional Scaling: Euclidean")
plt.show()
```

I don't get any error when the code runs, but what I end up with is one row with two graphs. One graph is completely empty and not styled by prettyplotlib at all. The right side graphic seems to have both of my scatterplots in it.

I know that ppl.subplots is returning a matplotlib.figure.Figure and a numpy array consisting of two matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot. But I also admit that I don't quite get how axes and subplotting works. Hopefully it's just a simple mistake somewhere.

Comment: I mean, it looks like I'm doing the same thing as what is described here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ax[0] = ppl.scatter(ypos,xpos,label=each)` should be `ax[0].scatter(ypos,xpos,label=each)` and `ax[1] = ppl.scatter(ypos,xpos,label=each)` should be `ax[1].scatter(ypos,xpos,label=each)`, change those and see if your problem get solved.

I am quite sure that the issue is: you are calling `ppl.scatter(...)`, which will try to draw on the current axis, which is the 1st axes of 2 axes you generated (and it is the left one)

Also you may find that in the end, the `ax` list contains two `matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`s, bot two `axis` as you may expect.

---

Since the solution above removes the prettiness of `prettyplot`, we shall use an alternative solution, which is to change the current working axis, by adding:

```
plt.sca(ax[0_or_1])
```

Before `ppl.scatter()`, inside each loop.

Comment: That did something. I ended up with a scatter plot in each of the two subplots, but now all the prettiness from prettyplotlib is gone. I just have default ugly. I wonder if this is maybe something that prettyplotlib is not able to support at this time.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at `seaborn`: http://www.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/plotting_distributions.html. No offense, absolutely, to the author of `pettyplot` :).

Comment: That change worked! Thank you very much. And I'll take a look at seaborn.

Comment: I think you can actually pass an `Axes` object to the prettyplotlib functions, so you don't need to mess around with making them "active".

Comment: You can do that, but when you do `ppl.plot(x,y,axes=ax[0])` it clears all other axis. Which renders it pretty much useless regarding subplots, in my opinion.

Comment: Turns out it works if you use ppl.plot(x,y,ax=ax[0])